# Module name within class name

Tags: ruby, module, naming

While refactoring my **User** class, I created a new **UserService** class. After some work I decided to move all user related operations into a new microservice which resides under the "User" namespace.

My first move would be having **User::UserService** which seems a little bit redundant, but somehow **User::Service** also sounds fishy or plain lazy typing.

What is the common naming convention on popular Ruby gems for this case

Answer (score 0):

After some trials my current choice is the seemly redundant **User::UserService**

The reason is that **UserService** is the first natural move of refactoring and introducing too early the **User::** namespace might be a symptom of over-design.

As the code matures renaming UserService to User::Service everywhere is an unnecessary pain, specially since it is possible to create an alias on the global namespace.

Inside the **User** namespace using just **Service** is a tad ambiguous, and having to type long redundant names from other namespaces might be an alarm about the module coupling.